# Can users get DB info from my software if using MySQL Connector

Tags: c#, mysql, security, connector

I am using MySQL Connector with my C# project to directly connect to a database to store statistical information. My question is if I release this project and someone has the willingness to try to access my database, can they grab the connection string to my database from within the software? I am using the SQL Connector so I can save data in real time and not generate massive HTTP requests, for those wondering why don't I just send the data in an HTTP req.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.  This is why they encourage the N-Tier approach.  Your application should be going through a .NET webservice, WCF Service, RIA Services, etc.  Your service would then in access the database and edit, insert, select the data from the database.  Of course your service will be responsible for some type of authentication process and determine which roles and functionality will be available.  For instance some logins may only have read access to the Orders table.  Some may have full blown admin rights of read/write/edit.  Some logins may have only read access to the customers table or maybe even only to their own customer record, etc.

You never want to expose your database login credentials to anything outside of your own network.  Even if you are using Obfustication or encryption if your app is connecting directly to the database at some point it has to send those credientials and this gives the hacker an opportunity to intercept or capture those values.

By using an N-Tier architecture the user has know a login/username that is not their own in order to gain more privelages.  Even through SSL who cares if they crack how to gain access to the webservice using their own username/password if it doens't give them any more access than it does through your program it is not a big deal.  They have to learn/steal someone else's password perhaps the Admins username/password which you can easily fix by changing once a month.

You mentioned sending the connection string in an HTTP request.  As soon as someone hacks that you can change your database username/password all you want but they already know how to hack that.  In other words never put your sa/DBOwner username passoword in your app.  In order for it to be secure you need to be going through some type of web service which requires a username and password and that is responsible for determining the user's priveleges.  The service should be on your own network so they would have to hack the web server or IIS in order to actually break into your database.

Some people go so far as to encrypt the username/password of the database in the config file of the webservice but it's not really necessary unless you are working in a large corporation where many admins have access to the config file but only a handfull of them should be able to access the database.  In my opinion plain text in the config file is fine unless the data is super sensitive and you have multiple people that are able to access the config file that shouldn't know the username/password.  The whole point to this is that only people in your corporation have access to the config file...the average joe running the application that isn't in your corporation should never have any way of getting this unless they physically hack into your IIS server...in which case you got bigger problems.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, if they will decompile your application. You can obfuscate your application (*I don't prefer to do this. It might damage your application. But if you do, there are lots of obsfucator in the internet.*). For me, the best way to do this is creating a `Settings` file and inside it are the encrypted string, such as database name, location, username and password.

Comment: That's a really good idea. Didn't even think of that. Thank you.

Comment: All still hackable and why the N-Tier approach is recommened to avoid someone gaining full blown sa/DBOwner privelages

Comment: at somepoint your code is still passing the full connection string to the database even you break appart and encrypt the database name, user name, password, server.  My point is that even if you go this route eventually your app needs to decrypt this and send the connection string.  This is not full proof by any means.

Answer (score 1):

It is always possible to pull a plain-text string out of an executable file, although not always practical.  If you want to beef up security a little, a couple things come to mind:

-obfuscate the connection string (or just the password) by storing it in pieces all over your application, but this might not be pretty.

-limit the access of the user you hard-code into the application

-store the password encrypted, which is still just obfuscation if the key is stored in the application (there is a nice AES library in the .NET Encryption libraries.)